# Demonstrate that the matrix $\pmatrix{ x_2^2 && -x_1x_2 \\ -x_1x_2 && x_1^2}$ represents a $2^{\text{nd}}$ order tensor.

Tags: tensors

Demonstrate that matrix $T$  represents a $2^{\text{nd}}$ order tensor.

$T = \pmatrix{ x_2^2 && -x_1x_2 \\ -x_1x_2 && x_1^2}.$

To show that $T_{ij}' = L_{ik}L_{jn}T_{kn}$, I would have to find a general form for $T_{ij}',$ but I'm not sure how to do that. The closest I got was $(-1)^{i+j}x_{3-i}x_{3-j}$, but that's not something I can use.

Comment: what you mean for *demonstrate*?

Comment: I guess 'show'?

Comment: usually when speaking of tensors it got to be clear which is the ground vector space, is it clear this for you?

Comment: what do you mean by 'ground'?

Comment: the place where we stand, but in our discussion the vector space where all is happening

Comment: hmm, it could be $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1):

You can find the contraction between your tensor and the second order tensor $x_{i}x_{j}$. If the contraction gives you an invariant then $T_{ij}$ is a second order tensor. Let $T_{ij}$ be the components of your tensor. Then, using Einstein summation notation, $T_{ij}x_{i}x_{j} = T_{11}x_{1}x_{1} + T_{12}x_{1}x_{2} + T_{21}x_{2}x_{1} + T_{22}x_{2}x_{2} = 0$ (evaluate it). The summation runs from one to two because your tensor is in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Now zero is an invariant (i.e. a scalar/ zeroth order tensor),and hence by the quotient rule, $T_{ij}$ is a second order tensor.